# angular 6 warning for using formControlName and ngModel

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel, angular-reactive-forms

I recently upgraded the angular version to 6-rc. I got following warning

> It looks like you're using ngModel on the same form field as
>   formControlName. Support for using the ngModel input property and
>   ngModelChange event with reactive form directives has been deprecated
>   in Angular v6 and will be removed in Angular v7
>
> For more information on this, see our API docs here:
>       https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel

What does it say exactly? the link does not have any fragment for `#use-with-ngmodel`

I guess I need to remove `ngModel` and use formGroup as my data binding object.

Comment: You need to go to the `next` docs: https://next.angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel; while v6 is in release candidate the docs still refer to v5.

Comment: Curiosity: Why do you want use [(ngModel)] and formControlName in the same input tag?

Comment: I have started using ngModel from angular 2 beta then added formControl. Now couldn't change this for many forms

Comment: We used `ngModel` for data and `formControl` for validation.

Comment: @Akshay We did the same thing. It seems too big of a job to change the whole app to manually get/set values from reactive form controls.

Comment: Aren't there any shortcut for getter/setter in Angular 6 reactive forms just like in C#.net like this "string _myProperty { get; set; }"? If you have a lot of inputs in one form wouldn't your code become too hard to read?

Comment: All of us who work with Angular are geting more and more completely out of the real, web programing World.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Now you can find the documentation here:

https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel-is-deprecated

So you have 3 options:

1. use Reactive forms
2. use Template driven forms
3. silence warning (not recommended)

```
<!-- language: lang-ts -->

    imports: [
      ReactiveFormsModule.withConfig({warnOnNgModelWithFormControl: 'never'});
    ]
```

Comment: Oh my god. What's the point of changing syntax and things that work all the time? I spent like a day upgrading to Angular 6 to now find this. I noticed my onchange selection events weren't firing. It was because they changed the freaking syntax from `onChange` to `selectionChange`. Really useful.

Comment: And there's more: for common inputs (text, textarea, select, checkbox, etc.), now, Angular does the disable(ing) *mandatory* through the Reactive Form config... nice... you can not use all-time-used *disabled=true*. And worst: if you make your own ui-components library... Angular might not have a clue of what is *disabled*... nice....

Comment: For a brand new app in the making, which of the above 3 alternatives would you recommend ?

Comment: @Stephane I would recommend using reactive forms

Comment: how do you get the value in reactive forms without ngmodel

Comment: if they remove it in angular 7, what will be the counter part? thanks

Answer (score 32):

Remove `[(ngModel)]` from every field within formGroup contains `formControlName`  and set value in controller class as follows simply `this.form.get('first').setValue('some value');` do not close or silence warnings explicitly.
And get value as

```
this.form.get('first').value
```

Another approach to achieve functionality is more simple.

```
this.form.controls.first.setValue('some Value');
```

And get value using form group as

```
this.holidaysForm.value.first;
```

Comment: yes but I wrote a peace of code from angular documentation for better understanding

Comment: Thanks for the example trying to improve reading and understanding the docs

Comment: so how do you get the value without ngmodel

Comment: @Flash, `this.form.get('fieldName').value`

Answer (score 5):

add

```
[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
```

You can read more from angular website https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel

Comment: I think a lot of people are confused with the fact that Angular is deprecating support for `ngModel` to work with `formControlName`  rather than completely deprecating `ngModel`.

Comment: does this mean template driven forms will be gone and people should use reactive forms instead?

Answer (score 0):

So I stumbled upon this when trying to display users' avatars in `mat-select`:

```
<mat-form-field [formGroup]="assignedToFormGroup">
<mat-select placeholder="Assign to" [(ngModel)]="assignedTo" formControlName="assignTo">
  <mat-select-trigger>
    <img style="vertical-align:middle;" aria-hidden
      src="{{assignedToFormGroup.controls['assignTo'].value.photoUrl}}" height="20" />
    <span>@{{assignedToFormGroup.controls['assignTo'].value.userName}}</span>
  </mat-select-trigger>
  <!-- {{user.userName}} -->
  <mat-option *ngFor="let user of members" [value]="user">
    <img style="vertical-align:middle;" aria-hidden src="{{user.photoUrl}}" height="20" />
    <span>@{{user.userName}}</span>
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

In controller, the formGroup was defined this way:

```
public assignedToFormGroup: FormGroup;
```

I followed Sohail's advice and removed `[(ngModel)]` from my HTML code:

```
<mat-form-field [formGroup]="assignedToFormGroup">
<mat-select placeholder="Assign to" formControlName="assignTo">
  <mat-select-trigger>
    <img style="vertical-align:middle;" aria-hidden
      src="{{assignedToFormGroup.controls['assignTo'].value.photoUrl}}" height="20" />
    <span>@{{assignedToFormGroup.controls['assignTo'].value.userName}}</span>
  </mat-select-trigger>
  <!-- {{user.userName}} -->
  <mat-option *ngFor="let user of members" [value]="user">
    <img style="vertical-align:middle;" aria-hidden src="{{user.photoUrl}}" height="20" />
    <span>@{{user.userName}}</span>
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

That gave me errors when opening page - I tried to load photoUrl and userName from null, because by removing [(ngModel)] I also removed default selection in `mat-select`.

So I modified my controller to do the following:
1. Constructor:

```
this.assignedToFormGroup.controls['assignTo'].setValue({photoUrl: '', userName: ''});
```

2. Button action where I save my form - added following line:

   `let assignedTo = this.assignedToFormGroup.controls['assignTo'].value;`

That actually worked. Now I'm setting default selection on page load and read selected value when submitting the form.
I'm aware that it's not the best and prettiest solution, but I thought I'll share it - might be a good starting point for better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same warning when I use [(ngMode)] together with [formControlName] in an embedded custom control. My form is built dynamicly using formBuilder.array([]) and I have to stay with [formControlName]:

```
this.searchForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      dynamicFormArray: this.formBuilder.array([])
});
```

But after I removed [(ngMode)] which is two-way bounding, I can no longer get the user input value from the embedded custom control using form.value (though I can see the value inside the embedded control)!

After painful strugging for some time, I've finally found a solution to make the user input value from the embedded contorl available to form.value. The key is to use patchValue for the dyanmicFormArray (not the form itself or formBuilder.group!):

```
this.dynamicFormArray.patchValue([{name: this.value}]);
```

Hope this could help some friends with similar issue.

Answer (score -2):

Using formControl(reactive Forms) is more straightforward coupled with Rxjs so Angular team changed use of it.

Change on html file

```
<!-- [ngModel]='model' (ngModelChange)='changed($event)' -->
```

to

```
[formControl]="myControl"
```

Change ts file

```
model: string;
  modelChanged: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

  changed(text: string) {
      this.modelChanged.next(text);
  }
  this.modelChanged.pipe(
      .subscribe(model => this.postErrorMessage = model);
```

to

```
this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      .subscribe(model => this.postErrorMessage = model);
```