# Removing ngModel from a component

Tags: angular-components, angular-forms, angular6

I have some components created for my angular application, and after upgrading my project to version 6 of Angular, I have received a message that worries me.

> It looks like you're using ngModel on the same form field as
>   formControl. 
>       Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with 
>       reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed 
>       in Angular v7.
>
> ```
> For more information on this, see our API docs here:
> https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlDirective#use-with-ngmodel
> ```

This is due to my following component:

```
<input type="text" id="{{id}}" name="{{name}}" [formControl]="ctrl" [(ngModel)]="value" appPfMaskCpf="999.999.999-99" placeholder="{{placeholder}}"
  class="form-control">

<div *ngIf="flagCpfInvalido && value.length > 0">
  <small class="text-danger">
    CPF inválido.
  </small>
  <br>
</div>
```

It is very simple, it receives an input and I check the value.

How can I remove the use of ngModel in this case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular 6 warning for using formControlName and ngModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49918503/angular-6-warning-for-using-formcontrolname-and-ngmodel)

Answer (score 0):

**You should not be using `ngModel` which is part of template-driven form inside a Reactive form.**

In stead of setting values using `ngModel` you can set the value using `formControlName`: Ex:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
   <input formControlName="first">
</form>
```

Set this value in component: `this.form.get('first').setValue('some value');`

Or you can choose to silence the console warning for now:

```
imports: [
   ReactiveFormsModule.withConfig({warnOnNgModelWithFormControl: 'never'});
 ]
```

> To update your code before v7, you'll want to decide whether to stick with reactive form directives (and get/set values using reactive forms patterns) or switch over to template-driven directives.

More details are available in [documentation](https://next.angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName)