# How do I select an item in a ng-select list programmatically?

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

My application shows the user a list that uses `ng-select`. This list contains several items

- item 1
- item 2
- item N

The user can do one of two things with the previous list. He can choose an existing item, or he can add a new item. If the user adds a new item to the list, the new item needs to be automatically added to the list and selected.

I've already managed to implement the add-to-list functionality. However, I haven't found a way to implement the functionality to programmatically select an item in the list.

**Is there a way of doing so with ng-select?** Thanks in advance

Comment: You most definitely have to have some kind of value binding, take a look at `ngModel` or `ReactiveForms`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [(ngModel)]  associated with a typescript variable.

```
<ng-select[(ngModel)]="selectedItem">
    ....
</ng-select>
```

Programmatically set the variable = your last added item.

```
selectedItem:any;

functionAddItemToList(){
.....
this.selectedItem = NewItem_Just_Added

}
```

Comment: I tried to use [(ngModel)] and it works, but I get a warning that using ngModal along form controls is deprecated and shouldn't be used.

Comment: I didnt know you were using form control. I normally dont use them. Here you have some options for this waning. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49918503/angular-6-warning-for-using-formcontrolname-and-ngmodel